# Changing symbology of all layers in table of contents using ArcPy and ArcMap?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, symbology

[image: The image below is a screenshot of my ArcMap document with the ArcPy script that I have been using.]

I am attempting to put together a DEM of the U.S. I have thousands of contour elevation files that I have loaded into an ArcMap document. I need to change the symbology for all of the layers in order to represent variations in elevation. I have an ArcPy script that will change the symbology of a list of layers, based on the symbology of a layer assigned as the template.

How do I change the symbology of all of the layers in the table of contents at once?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are looking for ListLayers function. Here it is:
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/ListLayers/00s30000002n000000/

if you will take esri code:

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Project\Project.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df)
del mxd
```

This will give you a list of the layers to apply, keep in mind you have to list the data frame before the layers (and the [0] is the first data frame, usally "Layers").